# Docker Compose: services unable to resolve each other's hostnames

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, dns

Consider a simple Docker Compose file.

```yaml
version: "3.0"

networks:
  basic:

services:

  srv:
    image: alpine
    networks:
      basic:
          aliases:
            - server.nowhere.fake
    domainname: server.nowhere.fake
    entrypoint: tail -f

  cli:
    image: alpine
    networks:
      basic:
          aliases:
            - client.nowhere.fake
    domainname: client.nowhere.fake
    entrypoint: nslookup server.nowhere.fake
```

Successful DNS resolutions is easily shown.

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "tmp_basic" with the default driver
Creating tmp_srv_1 ... done
Creating tmp_cli_1 ... done
Attaching to tmp_srv_1, tmp_cli_1
cli_1  | Server:        127.0.0.11
cli_1  | Address:   127.0.0.11:53
cli_1  | 
cli_1  | Non-authoritative answer:
cli_1  | 
cli_1  | Non-authoritative answer:
cli_1  | Name:  server.nowhere.fake
cli_1  | Address: 192.168.192.2
cli_1  | 
tmp_cli_1 exited with code 0
```

However, a more manual approach yields less productive results.

```
$ docker-compose run -d srv
Creating network "tmp_basic" with the default driver
tmp_srv_run_8ff7ac6b8cc8
$ 
$ docker-compose run cli
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11:53

** server can't find server.nowhere.fake: NXDOMAIN

** server can't find server.nowhere.fake: NXDOMAIN
```

In fact, it seems irrelevant whether the server is running, as its address is not resolved.

For some scenarios, finer control is required, as with using `run` for single services instead of `up` for all, such as in cases of terminal interaction.

In my case, I am seeking to test terminal I/O using a tool that simulates a human, by providing prescribed responses to various prompts.

Why does the lookup fail when the container is started in a separate operation? What solution is available?

Comment: If you remove absolutely all of the `network:` and `domainname:` options, and try to `docker-compose run cli nslookup srv`, does that work?  (So, using Compose's default networking setup instead of trying to manually replace it?)  If you `docker-compose run -d srv`, is the container still running when you `docker-compose run` the second container?

Comment: @David: Yes, but I now realize that in either case, whether using the default versus a dedicated network, the test is subject to race conditions (or some other kind of random effect, such as persistent artifacts, though clearing the networks, images, and containers provides no guarantees of success).

Comment: I have formalized the problem and posted an [issue in the tracker](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9054) for Compose.

Comment: The two obvious things I see here are that `cli` does not `depends_on: [srv]` so the two containers may not be created in the order you want, and that `tail -f` probably isn't a correct command (there's no filename to tail) and will exit immediately; it's possible that `srv` is both created and destroyed before `cli` can start up.  Does it help to add the `depends_on:` line, and remove the `entrypoint:` line so that the `srv` container runs its normal main process?

Comment: @David: The command `tail -f` by design runs until terminated by signal. The purpose is to simulate a container that operates a network service, (i.e. a server runs until terminated). A `depends_on` attribute was removed, because it had unwanted side effects, including creating an unwanted build dependency, and forcing a container to be started without explicit invocation.